iCloud mail rules/filter organising
I'd like to have my iCloud Mail emails organised at source using rules/filters so when i access on iOS they would be pre-organised for better searchability. iCloud Mail (web assess) is unfortunately limited in that regard, can anyone recommend another way to do this?
2 options that I thought could work;

IMAP to gmail and use its filtering as it's much better than iCloud. unfortunately gmail can only pop3 fetch iCloud emails, so for me this is unusable.
use my home server with mail.app to apply rules and push to iCloud via IMAP. i would prefer to use a third party service like gmail if possible as i think it will be more reliable.

